# Hibernate OGM and MongoDB, query's result to a composite structure is incorrect

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I'm using Hibernate OGM (5.0.3.Final) with MongoDB.
I've persisted this composite [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmDt.png) with the strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE. When I try to query a TextNode, I found the properties "text" null, but if I check the DB with mongo shell, i can see that the properties text is not null. [Here the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APVUV.png). I report the code that I used below.

Node class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance( strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )

public abstract class Node {

private Set<NodeLink> children;

private String id;
private String name;

public Node(){
    children = new HashSet<>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Type(type = "objectid")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


@OneToMany( mappedBy="source" )
public Set<NodeLink> getChildren() {
    return children;
}
void setChildren(Set<NodeLink> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

}
```

NodeLink class:

```
@Entity
public class NodeLink {

private String id;

private Node source;
private Node target;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Type(type = "objectid")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
public Node getSource() {
    return source;
}
void setSource(Node source) {
    this.source = source;
}
public void assignSource(Node source) {
    setSource(source);
    source.getChildren().add(this);
}

@ManyToOne
public Node getTarget() {
    return target;
}
void setTarget(Node target) {
    this.target = target;
}
public void assignTarget(Node target) {
    setTarget(target);
}

}
```

SimpleNode class:

```
@Entity
public class SimpleNode extends Node {

public SimpleNode() {
    super();
}
}
```

TextNode class:

```
@Entity
public class TextNode extends Node {

private String text;

public TextNode() {
    super();
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainNode {
private static EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY;
private static EntityManager manager;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaHelps");
    manager = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();

    createDB();
    queryDB();
}

//
// CREATE DB
//

private static void createDB() {
    EntityTransaction transaction1 = manager.getTransaction();
    transaction1.begin();

    Node root1 = new SimpleNode();
    root1.setName("root");
    Node child1 = new SimpleNode();
    child1.setName("children1");
    TextNode child2 = new TextNode();
    child2.setName("children2");
    child2.setText("a text");

    NodeLink nl4=new NodeLink();
    nl4.assignSource(root1);
    nl4.assignTarget(child1);

    NodeLink nl3=new NodeLink();
    nl3.assignSource(root1);
    nl3.assignTarget(child2);

    manager.persist(root1);
    manager.persist(child1);
    manager.persist(child2);
    manager.persist(nl4);
    manager.persist(nl3);

    transaction1.commit();
}


//
// QUERY DB
//

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void queryDB() {
"db.Node.find({'type_id':"+"ObjectId('"+typeId+"')})";
    Node node = manager.find(SimpleNode.class,    "5832c8762fc11706a29125b5");
    print(node);
}

private static void print(Node n) {
    System.out.println(n.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + n.getName() + " : " + (n.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("TextNode")? ((TextNode)n).getText() : "") );
    for(NodeLink c : n.getChildren()) {
        print(c.getTarget());
    }
}

}
```

My question is: I found an error in Hibernate OGM or there is an error in my code? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm checking, one question: what kind of query are you running?

Comment: Could you give use a more details about the way you are getting the entities? There are some limitations about HQL queries and inheritance that I'm working on but I cannot replicate the error you are having.

Comment: You're right, missing the query, I edited the post by adding the main class

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue but it seems to work for me, one thing that I noticed is that you are using type_id as variable name in the query in stead of _id; Could that be the issue? I've added the test on a branch on my repository: https://github.com/DavideD/hibernate-ogm/commit/dbc3cf5391bc2204076022a263004c09009f827f Maybe you can have a look and see if you spot anything